# Is returning error objects in PHP bad habit?

Tags: php, error-handling

I'm new to php and I am a bit confused by the fact that there seems to be no error object communication from a method to its caller.

These two are the ways I learn to use:

1. If a method should not info the caller of the error it just triggers an error an if this is not E_USER_ERROR it just can return FALSE to tell the caller something went wrong.
2. On the other way if a method needs to send back some error info to the caller an exception should be raised.

Coming from COCOA I have learn to use exceptions on extraordinary conditions (non recoverable errors due to programmer mistakes). In any other case just pass an error object to the caller.

- Is the philosify different in PHP?
- Are exceptions the standar mechanism to send back error data to the caller?
- Should I avoid programming my own error objects and pass then as out param to the method to be consistent with PHP patterns?

Comment: I'm going to turn this around and ask "When is it preferable to return an error object rather than raise an exception?".

Answer (score 10, accepted):

PHP has two main mechanisms for indicating and handling errors in your program flow:

- [Error Handling and Logging](http://php.net/manual/en/book.errorfunc.php)
- [Exceptions](http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php)

Which to pick depends on your personal preference. Exceptions are objects, so if you want to do OOP or come from another language that also uses Exceptions, you might want to use them. Non-Exception based error handling is for all those Notices, Warning and Errors PHP can emit, as well as you own variants of those. If you want to turn these into Exceptions, have a look at [ErrorException](http://php.net/manual/en/class.errorexception.php).

However, like you already mentioned: exceptions are for non-recoverable situations. They are **not** for managing regular control flow. Consequently, Exceptions are not some sort of standard mechanism to send back error messages to a caller, e.g. you should not do:

```
class FooValidator
{
    public function isValid($valueToValidate)
    {
        if ($this->satisfiesRules($valueToValidate) {
            return true;
        }
        throw new ValidationException('Foo didnt satisfy rule Bar');
    }
}
```

and they try/catch that in the caller. A failed validation is a recoverable situation.

One option would be to introduce a [Notification Object](http://martinfowler.com/dslCatalog/notification.html):

```
class FooValidator
{
    public function isValid($valueToValidate, Notification $notification)
    {
        if ($this->satisfiesRules($valueToValidate) {
            return true;
        }
        $notification->addMessage('Foo didnt satisfy rule Bar');
        return false;
    }
}
```

In the above example, the Validator returns only a Boolean but can collect additional information about why the validation failed in the passed Notification object. This is much cleaner than returning an Error Object from the call, because we dont have to check the return type. If the validation returns false, we know we can check the Notification object. Since objects are passed by reference, we dont need to return the object from the call but simply access the collected messages from the caller.

Comment: I like this answer, but I haven't been convinced by the argument that you shouldn't use exceptions for flow control. Why not? Doesn't the propagation of exceptions allow an outer function at some level to recover from an error in the most appropriate way? We can almost always "recover" from something we didn't expect by returning a default value, but then the logic of assessing whether or not that return value is the result of a valid call or not is left up to the caller. An exception clearly indicates that something is wrong and propagates up to the most appropriate handler. Please educate me

Comment: @me232 An Exception indicates something exceptional has occurred (not just something wrong). A failed validation (as per example above) is not exceptional. There is no reason whatsoever to run this through the exception handling process. Also see http://www.c2.com/cgi/wiki?DontUseExceptionsForFlowControl and http://schlitt.info/opensource/blog/0724_python_good_bad_evil_03_flow_control_exceptions.html

Comment: I agree in your example the use of exception is fairly pointless, since a return value of false is probable adequate anyway. The function seems to be able to recover from the problem itself. Suppose you have a more complicated example of converting one object to another. Is it wrong to throw an exception if the argument isn't suitable for the conversion? Should all the potential callers implement some validation logic?

Comment: My policy on this is that if you are not expecting a function to be called with some argument in the first place then I am happy to use exceptions to indicate this, but I certainly agree it would be a bad and inefficient idea to use this in cases you actually expect to occur

Comment: @me232 in case of your conversion example the situation is likely exceptional. Another example would be Division by Zero. But you got two options: throw an Exception or return a [SpecialCase](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/specialCase.html).

Comment: Great answer. There seems to be some debate on how to use exceptions in PHP. Unfortunately the official documentation just show the tools but don't give conceptual guidance on them.

Answer (score 0):

almost everything is possible in PHP so there is not realy a best way.

take a look at Exceptions on php.net
http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php

Comment: I have painfully learn that for every language  almost everything is possible, This is why design patters make us life easier, avoiding us to reinvent the wheel and learn from others experience. The official docs never talk about error objects, that's why I ask.